# Как отрегулировать масштаб heatmap матрицы корреляций?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

```
id  Temperature Humidity    Light   CO2 HumidityRatio   Occupancy
date                            
2015-02-04 17:51:00 1   2.518315    0.278509    1.573666    0.364926    1.091690    1.0
2015-02-04 17:51:59 2   2.488814    0.277696    1.591637    0.341860    1.080489    1.0
2015-02-04 17:53:00 3   2.488814    0.273628    1.573666    0.340269    1.075822    1.0
2015-02-04 17:54:00 4   2.488814    0.265492    1.573666    0.323567    1.066489    1.0
2015-02-04 17:55:00 5   2.439646    0.265492    1.573666



plt.figure(figsize=(7,6))
corr = df.drop('id', axis=1).corr()
sns.heatmap(corr, cmap=sns.color_palette("RdBu_r", 1000), vmin=-1, center=0, annot=True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на графике верх и низ срезаны. Как полностью втиснуть квадратик в график?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YzGDML_wBZSJTGip3yZ1uk6HTTCSg_nD/view?usp=sharing
Как получены данные:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('datatraining.txt', sep=r',', engine='python', header=None, names = ['id', 'date','Temperature','Humidity','Light','CO2','HumidityRatio','Occupancy'])
df = df.drop([0])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.drop('date', axis=1, inplace=True)
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
def scale(df):
    return (df - df.mean()) / df.std()
df.Temperature = scale(df.Temperature)
df.Humidity = scale(df.Humidity)
df.Light = scale(df.Light)
df.CO2 = scale(df.CO2)
df.HumidityRatio = scale(df.HumidityRatio)
```

Comment: Вот плюсую автора за то, что она не поленилась и правильно составила вопрос, со всеми исходными данными.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к @strawdog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо

```
sns.heatmap(corr, cmap=sns.color_palette("RdBu_r", 1000), vmin=-1, center=0, annot=True)
```

Сделайте так:

```
ax = sns.heatmap(corr, cmap=sns.color_palette("RdBu_r", 1000), vmin=-1, center=0, annot=True)
i, k = ax.get_ylim()
ax.set_ylim(i+0.5, k-0.5) #устанавливаем границы вручную
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Используйте специально предназначенную для этого функцию [`plt.tight_layout()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout.html) в конце:

```
sns.heatmap(corr, cmap=sns.color_palette("RdBu_r", 1000), vmin=-1, center=0, annot=True)
plt.tight_layout()
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
cols = ['LSTAT', 'INDUS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'MEDV']
plt.figure(figsize = (7,5))
ax = sns.heatmap(boston_df[cols].corr(),
cbar=True,
annot=True)
```